# Chrome lighthouse extension is returning 404 for existing routes

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse, angular-pwa

I am working on making an angular (9.1.4) app to be PWA. I'm using lighthouse chrome extension to check PWA features missing. But I'm facing a problem. Lighthouse works fine for the login page, it shows the page is PWA with the right mark. But after login and navigating to other pages, the lighthouse doesn't work and returns 404 not found error.

I have spent a lot of time to find a solution for this but nothing came up. I have seen a few posts with similar problem, but they got no solutions either. So, I really appreciate any kind of suggestions. I would also appreciate it if you could recommend an alternative for lighthouse.

Comment: If you use Lighthouse in the browser uncheck "clear storage" at the top of the page, navigate as normal and then test. If that doesn't work then you are going to have to use something like puppeteer in conjunction with Lighthouse. Also if it is returning a 404 then you need to check what happens if you navigate to a page before the PWA has been installed as you may have an issue there.

Comment: I find it weird too, that there seems to be no answer for this. I'm not seeing a "clear storage" thing to uncheck as per Graham's comment either.

Comment: Hi, try to use local-web-server npm package and run ws --spa index.html -p 4200 under dist folder. Fixed it using local-web-server for pages other than the home page.